# Jquery date validator not receiving value

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, date

I need to make a validation for two dates: start_date and end_date, after I write them in the inputs. The validation is working fine but I would like to have the option of giving the end_date the value null, or 0. When I don't write anything in the second input, it still gives me the error message from jQuery. Can you please help me?

```
$.validator.addMethod("enddate", function(value, element) {
    alert(value);
    if (value != null) {
        var startdatevalue = $(".startdate").val();
        return Date.parse(startdatevalue) < Date.parse(value);
    }
}, "End date must be greater than start date!");
```

And this is my html:

```
<tr>
    <td>Start date</td>
    <td><input type="text"  id="startDate" name="startDate" class="startdate"  value="<fmt:formatDate pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" value="${List.startDate}" />"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>End date</td>
    <td><input type="text"  id="endDate" name="endDate" class="enddate" value="<fmt:formatDate pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" value="${List.endDate}"/>"/></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Your validator does not return anything if the value is null, so it's not validating if you don't write anything in the second input

Comment: I think it is the same thing, instead of id I wrote the class. no?

Comment: your enddate html is not valid
in the javascript the code if (value != null)
will test for value NOT being null, undefined, 0, and '' 
you should use the strict form e.g. value !== '' - as an input box will always return a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to validate what i needed, in order to have the start_date<=end_date - with jquery datepicker:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      $("#startDate").datepicker({

          dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',

          numberOfMonths: 1,

          onSelect: function(selected) {

            $("#endDate").datepicker("option","minDate", selected);

          }

      });

      $("#endDate").datepicker({

          dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',

          numberOfMonths: 1,

          onSelect: function(selected) {

              $("#startDate").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected);

          }

      }); 

    });
```

I thought someone else could use this answer, too.
Thanks again for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Before checking startdate is less than enddate, make ensure enddate has value.

Answer (score 0):

need to return some data if it's null or 0

```
$.validator.addMethod("enddate", function(value, element) {
    alert(value);

    // Valid if null or 0
    if (value == null || value == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    // else compare dates
    var startdatevalue = $(".startdate").val();
    return Date.parse(startdatevalue) < Date.parse(value);
}, "End date must be greater than start date!");
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but this only works for the case when I don't write anything in the end_date input. If I do, the validation is not executed correctly..